# Unable to create a successful connection for data source in Weblogic server 12.2.1.3 console

Tags: weblogic

I am getting the below error when I create a new data source in WebLogic Server 12.2.1.3.0 after I installed the server today.

I have already created and tested the same in Java 1.7 using WebLogic Server 12.1.3.0.0.

This is failing now that I have updated to Java 1.8 using WebLogic 12.2.1.3.0.

**Error:**

```
Messages

Message icon - Error Connection test failed.

Message icon - Error [FMWGEN][DB2 JDBC Driver]Error establishing socket to host and port: powud03a.apmoller.net:60004. Reason: Connection timed out: connect
weblogic.jdbc.db2base.ddcp.b(Unknown Source)
weblogic.jdbc.db2base.ddcp.a(Unknown Source)
weblogic.jdbc.db2base.ddco.b(Unknown Source)
weblogic.jdbc.db2base.ddco.a(Unknown Source)
weblogic.jdbc.db2.drda.ddf.(Unknown Source)
weblogic.jdbc.db2.DB2ImplConnection.k(Unknown Source)
weblogic.jdbc.db2.DB2ImplConnection.d(Unknown Source)
weblogic.jdbc.db2base.BaseConnection.b(Unknown Source)
weblogic.jdbc.db2base.BaseConnection.k(Unknown Source)
weblogic.jdbc.db2base.BaseConnection.b(Unknown Source)
weblogic.jdbc.db2base.BaseConnection.a(Unknown Source)
weblogic.jdbcx.db2base.ddx.a(Unknown Source)
weblogic.jdbcx.db2base.ddx.getXAConnection(Unknown Source)
weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.DataSourceUtil.testConnection0(DataSourceUtil.java:387)
weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.DataSourceUtil.access$000(DataSourceUtil.java:24)
weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.DataSourceUtil$1.run(DataSourceUtil.java:285)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.DataSourceUtil.testConnection(DataSourceUtil.java:282)
com.bea.console.utils.jdbc.JDBCUtils.testConnection(JDBCUtils.java:937)
com.bea.console.actions.jdbc.datasources.createjdbcdatasource.CreateJDBCDataSource.testConnectionConfiguration(CreateJDBCDataSource.java:524)
...
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. The error message states that it's a connection error, did you double check whether the database server is up and running and can be reached from your system?

Comment: Yes, I have tried to connect with SQLDev and it seems to be solved now. The addition done in the file setDomainEnv.cmd under the weblogic folder was not saved properly. After adding the last line below, it works now:      if NOT "%WEBLOGIC_EXTENSION_DIRS%"=="" (
 set JAVA_OPTIONS=%JAVA_OPTIONS% -Dweblogic.ext.dirs=%WEBLOGIC_EXTENSION_DIRS%
)

set JAVA_OPTIONS=%JAVA_OPTIONS% -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true